# C# results into Access DB - "Additional information: Data type mismatch in criteria expression."

Tags: c#, ms-access

I am writing the program in C# to insert information into an Access database. So, using the following C# statement, and the proceeding form, I need to know what data types my Access fields have to be. (ie; {0}=int, {1}=nchar)
I think, until I get it figured out,

```
    ![string vsql = string.Format("insert into Log values " +
        "('{0}','{1}','{2}','{3}','{4}','{5}','{6}')",
        comboBox1.Text,                 //(type?)
        comboBox2.Text,                 //(type?)   
        int.Parse(textBox1.Text),       //I want this to be float (possible?)
        int.Parse(textBox1.Text),       //I want this to be float (possible?)
        textBox2.Text,                  //(type?)
        textBox3.Text,                  //(type?)
        addRemove);                     //(type?)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
string vsql = string.Format("insert into Log values " +
        "('{0}','{1}',{2},{3},'{4}',#{5}#,'{6}')",
        comboBox1.Text,           //string field
        comboBox2.Text,           //string field
        int.Parse(textBox1.Text), //don't wrap this in quotes if you want it as a float
        int.Parse(textBox1.Text), //same as above
        textBox2.Text,            //this is a DateTime field - you probably need to wrap with # marks.
        textBox3.Text,            //string field
        addRemove                 //bool field
        );
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    private void SaveRecord()
    {
        string connString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["dbx"].ConnectionString;
        string cmdString = "INSERT INTO tblBasicInfo (SName, FName, Gender, DOB, DOBnW, Nationality, FCNICNo, FOccup, Religion, Cell, Fone, Address, AdmNo, ClassofAdm, ClassofReading, TranFacility, Remarks, TransportChr, Picture, SpecialRemarks) Values (@SName, @FName, @Gender, @DOB, @DOBnW, @Nationality, @FCNICNo, @FOccup, @Religion, @Cell, @Fone, @Address, @AdmNo, @ClassofAdm, @ClassofReading, @TranFacility, @Remarks, @TransportChr, @Picture, @SpecialRemarks)";
        using (OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection(connString))
        {
            using (OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(cmdString, con))
            {
                con.Open();
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SName", NametextBox.Text);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FName", FNametextBox.Text);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Gender", GendercomboBox.Text);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DOB", (InFiguredateTimePicker.Text));
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DOBnW", InWordstextBox.Text);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Nationality", NationalitytextBox.Text);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FCNICNo", FCNICNotextBox.Text);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FOccup", FOccuptextBox.Text);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Religion", ReligiontextBox.Text);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Cell", CelltextBox.Text);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Fone", PhonetextBox.Text);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Address", AddresstextBox.Text);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@AdmNo", AdmNotextBox.Text);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ClassofAdm", ClassofAdmcomboBox.Text);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DateofAdm", (DateofAdmdateTimePicker.Text));
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ClassofReading", ClassOfReadcomboBox.Text);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@TranFacility", TransportFacilitytextBox.Text);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Remarks", RemarkscomboBox.Text);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@TransportChr", TransportFeetextBox.Text);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Picture", SavePhoto());
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SpecialRemarks", SRemarkstextBox.Text);


                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

                MessageBox.Show("Record is Saved Successfully.", "Success", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
                NametextBox.Clear();
                FNametextBox.Clear();
                NametextBox.Focus();
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: It's better to explain what you wrote before your code.